# How to apply opencv background subtraction to an image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to apply `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()` to this Image:

[image]

to eliminate all background brightness and only leave the two bright objects in the middle for further analysis. Is this the right approach for this task? If not, how would I do that?

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
sharp_img = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG().apply(img)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artur/Desktop/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    sharp_img = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG().apply(img)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG
```

**Edit**:

MOG does not seem to work.

Code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image.png')
sharp_img = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG().apply(img)
cv2.imwrite('image2.png', sharp_img)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artur/Desktop/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    sharp_img = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG().apply(img)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'bgsegm'
```

MOG2 seems to work but with no satisfying result:

Code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image.png')
sharp_img = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2().apply(img)
cv2.imwrite('image2.png', sharp_img)
```

Output Image:

[image]

I tried to play around with the args of the MOG2 Method from the docs but with no change.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Background substraction means that you have an image of your background (say street) and image where new objects appeared on top of that (say same street with people). In that case if you use background extractor - you will get image of people without street. You only have 1 image and how do you expect background extractor to know what is background and what is foreground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html), try this:

```
sharp_img = cv.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG().apply(img)
```

or

```
sharp_img = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2().apply(img)
```

Comment: Tried that before writing the thread. MOG didnt work so I assumed that MOG2 would not work either but it does. Unfortunately with no satisfactory result. Please take a look at the edit section.

Comment: yeah that doesn't seem correct, you could try applying some kind of thresholding on the original image, since it's grayscale, make every pixel that isn't higher than 200 become 0, and that should leave just the objects shown

Comment: I first did `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` and then applied `cv2. createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2 ()`. Results were good.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image.png')

max,min = img.max(),imgg.min()
print(max,min)  #helps in giving thresholding values 

threshold_img = cv2.threshold(blurred, 127, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) #good starting point to give t1 value as half of max value of image

cv2.imshow(threshold_img)
```

This approach is a good starting point in your case, as you have two bright peaks that you want to separate from the noise. Once you have identified the required threshold limits, you should be able to isolate the two spots from the noise in the background. You can further use `cv2.erode` and `cv2.dilate` if needed to remove further noise.